# cordova-plugin-screen-orientation doesn't work with mobileFirst CLI

Tags: cordova-plugins, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I have been trying to use cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 1.4.0 "Screen Orientation" in my mfp cli cordova project, but it never works

I have used the exact same code outside of the mfp platform and it works just fine

any known issues with this?

Comment: Derek, what are the symptoms you see when using the plugin?

Comment: Trying to lock the screen to landscape doesnt work, works outside of mfp with the exact same cordova app

Comment: I suspect you'll need to open a PMR.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there may be a defect with the mfp cordova integration that prevents the plug-in from working as advertised. You will need to open a PMR (support ticket) in order for the development team to further investigate it. If you choose to open it, please mention the PMR number.